# Mathf.Clamp for velocity not working

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a player and a track, i have applied the velocity to the player so that he can move either right or left within the road.

The player is rigid body(rb) and i am applying the velocity to move the player.

For moving the player to left only in the road i have applied to following:

```
Vector2 clampPos = new Vector2 (-playerSpeed, 0);
clampPos.x = Mathf.Clamp (clampPos.x, -maxPoistion, maxPoistion);
rb.velocity = clampPos;
```

But the player is still moving outside the max position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of clamping the velocity, We should clamp the position.

```
rb.velocity = new Vector2 (playerSpeed, 0);
Vector2 clampPos = rb.position;
clampPos.x = Mathf.Clamp (clampPos.x, -maxPoistion,maxPoistion);
rb.position = clampPos;
```